# facebook no comments

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I`m using facebook comments plugin on my web page. When I post comment, it showing on the wall in the FB. But when i go to my web page from FB, no comments are showing.
Code:

`

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="166856086729262">
<div id="fb_comm" style="padding-left: 10px;>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1">
<fb:comments href="http://".$xid." width="750" num_posts="5"></fb:comments>
</div>
```

`
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your site's URL instead of href="http://".$xid."

Facebook's plugin links between the application you're running and the URL.